# After running an AJAX call, jquery code does not execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a website which uses pagination, and some filtering with jQuery and AJAX. All works well up until the point I changed my links to Javascript links.

Being on the homepage and not having used any filtering or pagination all works as expected. After I have used pagination or a filtering (effectively using an AJAX call for both) my JavaScript links do not work anymore.

The JavaScript for the link is:

```
$(function(){
    $( ".artikel_box_lk .button" ).click(function( e ) {
        window.open( "/lk/" + $( this ).attr("rel"), "_blank");
    });
});
```

And the code for the pagination:

```
function loadData(page){                   
    loading_show();
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/load_data.php",
        data: dataToSend,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
            {   
                loading_hide();
                $("#container").html(msg);                          
            });
        }
    });
}
```

My guess is that the javascript does not get reloaded on the AJAX call as only part of the page is reloaded, but I am unsure if this is the case and on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your javascript is not loaded after postback. Try adding your function inside **pageLoad** on **Webpage** like :

```
function pageLoad()
{
    $( ".artikel_box_lk .button" ).click(function( e ) {
        window.open( "/lk/" + $( this ).attr("rel"), "_blank");
    });
}
```

Comment: I am not sure where to place this function now? Does it need to be in the loadData function? or in the success function of the AJAX call? Or somewhere else? Sorry for the noob questions!

Comment: You should add it in Webpage(.aspx or .html or anytype webpage) inside javascript tag, it will re-register link after server postback.

Comment: Ah, ok... I think I have it working now. I have added the call to the function in my load_data.php file where it is now being called each time the page gets reloaded by AJAX. Correct? Anyway thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Do [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
 $( "#container" ).on ("click",".artikel_box_lk .button" ,function( e ) {
        window.open( "/lk/" + $( this ).attr("rel"), "_blank");
    });
```

Comment: If I use this code instead my links are not working at all. I am probably missing something simple here.